# Request a single report page in Remote Report Viewer / ServerReport

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I'm trying to get only one page from a remote report but instead I get a whole multi-paged report from a remote reporting server:

```
var rsReports = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer
{
    ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote,
    ShowParameterPrompts = false,
    CurrentPage = page // In theory this should be enough, but makes absolutely no difference
}
rsReports.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials(username, password, domain);
rsReports.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = remoteServerUrl;
rsReports.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
rsReports.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
rsReports.ServerReport.Refresh();

return rsReports.ServerReport.Render("HTML4.0"); // Returns a byte[] of html containing all report pages
```

Is there a way to request only 1 single page from the remote reporting server?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ReportExecution api you will find a parameter called DeviceInfo. This is an xml configuration structure that contains extra information for multiple output devices targeted. One of the properties for HTML40 is called [Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395.aspx). The `DeviceInformation.Section` property allows you to specify a page within the report to return. How does this relate to the ReportViewer control, well the report viewer control's content is returned in html by default so this would be an available option if you could set the `DeviceInfo` structure with your render method. I was able to find information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx) pertaining to setting the device information via url. Perhaps this helps.

**Actually, I re-read your question** and it seems that you are asking can you retrieve only page 10 of a 600 page report in such a way that all 600 pages are not rendered and only page 1/1 is returned instead of 10/??? is that correct? If so, then you will have to put a page filter mechanism in either your dataset or the report element itself. The default behavior is to render enough of the report to get paging metrics. So, sometimes you will see page 1/3 and sometimes page 1/600 (after you select last page) and other times page 1/???, that information can be obtained after the report is rendered in `RenderInfo`. If you want the viewer to think there is only one page then you will have to trick it. My first suggestion will work if you want page 10/??? to come back with paging and all.

Comment: Ideally I would not want to get all 600 pages from the server. In fact I don't want the server to query the database to get records to fill 600 pages. Let's assume I have no access to modify the reports and work with what I have on the reporting server. I suspect there must be a way to achieve that, since when I query my reports on the Reporting Server directly it seems to query database for each page separately instead of downloading the whole thing.

Comment: If you force it to the last page >> then it will iterate all pages. That being said, if you need page 60 of 300 then 60 pages will be iterated. That's why suggested making a filter like take and skip parameters, if your detail data starts and ends on the same one.